# Yii 1 URL manager template

Tags: php, yii

Good afternoon!
Tell me how to set the type of URL, that URL to type www.mysite.ru/content/xmd/glass/soro-10
I went to in /models/content/DefaultController.php
in the public function actionIndex($param)
and that would be in the $param part fell url = xmd / glass / soro-10

You can write like this
/content///' => 'content/default/index/param1//param2//param3/',
But Problem is that as a result in action movie should be 3 parameters (and I would like that to the whole line was in one variable), as well as all of a sudden I have more than 3 parameters to pass - so have Minya in the config and specify additional options. I would like to get a more comfortable pattern.

Thanks in advance to tell all and sorry for bad English!

Answer (score 0):

You can add this rule to the url manager:

```
'content/<param:.+>' => '/content/default/index'
```

When you access www.mysite.ru/content/xmd/glass/soro-10, `$param` in `actionIndex($param)` will now contain `xmd/glass/soro-10`.

More info: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#using-named-parameters